# Do MySQL MyISAM Tables handle null in indexes?

Tags: mysql, isnull

I created this MySQL table using MySQL 5.5:

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableOne
    -> (high INT NOT NULL, low INT NOT NULL, current INT NULL, 
    -> INDEX connect (low, current), INDEX theHigh (high), INDEX theCurrent (current));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
```

Then I tested out two queries:

```
mysql> describe SELECT * FROM TableOne WHERE current IS NOT NULL;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TableOne | ALL  | theCurrent    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9238 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe SELECT * FROM TableOne WHERE current = 0;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TableOne | ref  | theCurrent    | theCurrent | 5       | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

??? I realize that NULL is special.  I realize that in a "UNIQUE" index you're still allowed multiple NULL values, whereas you wouldn't, for example, be allowed multiple "0" values.  But why does the index not get used when searching for NULL values?  Is that a regular occurrence?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/is-null-optimization.html explains your issue in the first few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> But why does the index not get used when searching for NULL values?

NULL is a special sort of value in SQL ... it fails all the comparison tests like `=`, `<>`, `<=` and so forth. So ordinary BTREE ordered indexes can make no sense of it.

> Is that a regular occurrence?

It is indeed.